# L'infinito usato come soggetto non forma predicato?

Tags: grammatical-analysis, infinitive

Su [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analisi_logica_del_periodo), per quanto riguarda l'analisi del periodo, leggo che:

> l'infinito usato come soggetto non forma predicato. Esempio: "Sciare è la mia passione" è un'unica proposizione;

Ma è sempre vero? Sono piuttosto confusa. Ecco due esempi in cui non so proprio decidermi. Quale regola devo seguire?

***Il capire qualcosa*** è una gioia ma solo se legato a uno sforzo. 
Analisi del periodo

- Il capire qualcosa=sub. sogg. 1st grado
- è una gioia=princ.
- ma solo se legato a uno sforzo=sub condizionale 1st grado

***Leggere una guida***, saltando da un aeroporto all’altro, non equivale alla lenta faticosa acquisizione per osmosi degli umori della terra cui, con il treno, si rimane attaccati.
Analisi del periodo

- Leggere una guida non equivale alla lenta faticosa acquisizione per osmosi degli umori della terra=princ.
- saltando da un aeroporto all’altro=sub. modale 1st grado
- cui, con il treno, si rimane attaccati=sub. relativa 2nd grado

Comment: Intanto, la Wikipedia, e in particolare quella italiana, la lascerei perdere. Poi: qui il problema, più che l'analisi del periodo, riguarda l'uso dell'infinito, e precisamente quando considerarlo come una voce verbale e quando sostantivato. Non ho tempo di trascriverlo, ma se hai l'“Italiano” di Serianni, ti consiglio di dare un'occhiata a XI, 406-411, sulla difficoltà di distinguere i due casi, distinzione che – a parte alcuni casi ovvî – è tutt'altro che puramente formale.

Comment: Fare una foto e postarla sarebbe possibile? Purtroppo non ho quel libro!

Answer (score 2):

'il capire' direi sia il soggetto della principale, e anche (sottointeso) della subordinata:

```
Il capire è una gioia solo se (il capire) è legato a uno sforzo.
```

Non direi che cambia nel caso di 'il capire qualcosa', anche se non saprei come qualificare grammaticalmente 'qualcosa', forse una apposizione.